# Oracle db - get rid of doubled rows

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle database with a table like this:

```
yr      op    v1   v2   v3
2014    op1   10   15   20
2014    op1   10   15   20
2014    op1   10   15   20
2015    op2   33   44   55
2015    op2   33   44   55
2015    op3   100  200  300
2015    op3   100  200  300
2015    op3   100  200  300
```

how can I get rid of values that are more than one time on each year/op? my table should look like this:

```
yr      op    v1   v2   v3
2014    op1   10   15   20
2014    op1   0    0    0
2014    op1   0    0    0
2015    op2   33   44   55
2015    op2   0    0    0
2015    op3   100  200  300
2015    op3   0    0    0
2015    op3   0    0    0
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know which row to zero out and which row to retain non-zero values for?  Do you just want to pick arbitrarily?  What happens if the `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` values are different for two rows with the same `yr` and `op`?  Why do you want to have multiple rows in the table in the first place rather than making (`yr`, `op`) the key?

Comment: they are all the same because are calculated from other rows that I didn't put here...

Comment: the rows are from a view where I need that values on each row for other calcs but in the end I need to get rid of them.

Comment: How do you know which row to zero out and which row to retain non-zero values for? Do you just want to pick arbitrarily?

Comment: arbitrary - first occurence

Comment: OK.  And since the data is coming from a view, I assume that you don't really want to modify the data, you just want a query that replaces values with 0's.

Comment: I work to that view and I use a multiple WITH view1 AS( select FROM ...),  view2 AS (select...  from view1 ....) Select *  From view2.... and the last sequence I want to get rid of double sums on rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you want something like

```
SELECT yr,
       op,
       (case when rnk = 1
             then val1
             else 0
         end) val1,
       (case when rnk = 1
             then val2
             else 0
          end) val2,
       (case when rnk = 1
             then val3
             else 0
         end)
  FROM( SELECT a.*,
               row_number() over (partition by yr, op) rnk
          FROM your_view a )
```